# Firefox Image Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, image, firefox, html5-canvas

I'm going steadily more mad if this continues:

Firefox versions 6 - 13 seem to have serious image-rendering performance issues on Mac and Windows XP.

Whether I move multiple Images around in a DIV via `position: absolute; left: Xpx` or using CSS3 `transform: translateX(Xpx);` or *even in a canvas element* the images stutter heavily while being moved around.

You can check my latest Canvas test here: http://jsfiddle.net/5YCmH/6/

My question is; **why is this happening?**
As I see and read it on the web CSS3 and Canvas should be hardware accelerated by now.
So I checked the various settings in about:config and even reset them to default. Nothing works. While Safari and Chrome are rendering everything smoothly, Firefox looks like IE7.

I tested on 3 different machines, same problem everywhere. Whats happening people?
Any pointers or insight would be helpful!

PS:
I haven't used FF much since I switched to Chrome like one year ago. Before that I made an image sliding widget and tested it in FF 3.6.xx and it worked smoothly (using the `position: absolute; left: xx;` approach). Now I'm testing code I primarily developed in WebKit browsers also in FF and it doesn't work at all.

Is this real life? I feel funny.

**EDIT:**

Here's another fiddle showing the same stuttering with old-school animation: http://jsfiddle.net/XZAE6/3/

And with CSS3 `translateX()`: http://jsfiddle.net/h3UNk/3/

Comment: Because FF is slower than a 1 legged dog on tranquilizers? I tried your fiddle in my old comp, Win7 FF16 with 1gb dedicated video card, and it **does** have performance issues when compared to Chrome.

Comment: Yeah but why? I don't get it. With all the cool demos with canvas and CSS3 it *should* work or am I mistaken?

Comment: I'm running some tests, apparently Firefox has a much higher CPU peak in your fiddle than Chrome. Gecko tends to handle stuff much more diligently, hence it takes too much from the CPU and makes it run slower overall. I'd say this is more a performance issue to be submitted to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/) (as if they care about fixing anything which isn't their PDF reader) than here, but I'll post if I find a solution. Simon's answer makes sense as well, CPU-wise.

Comment: It's weird nonetheless, Firefox *should* have access to hardware acceleration, it shouldn't have such poor performance.. I'll +1 for the time being.

Comment: Yeah I think watching the RAM consumption doesn't help much because FF takes more on most sites I compared against FF and Chrome. I added 2 new fiddles.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: Yes, this is real life... `;)`

Comment: Thanks! I still feel like having the worst nightmare ever.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could possibly be remedied by using smaller images. Your aquatics.jpg is 193 kilobytes and velodrome.jpg 140 kilobytes. I'm sure the size can be reduced by at least 50 % without noticeable loss of image quality.

Comment: That's not possible in my case. The images will most likely get bigger. I added 2 new fiddles illustrating the problem with CSS3 and traditional style manipulation ..